# Which STM32 microcontroller has the most PWM channels?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, stm32

I need a MCU with a minimum of 32 PWM outputs and at least 1 analog input. Are there any STM32 MCU which satisfies the requirements?

I thought of multiplexing 16 PWM channels to 32 channels, but I would rather not as it would increase the size/cost. Are there any other suggested alternatives? The frequency doesn't matter that much as long as they're higher than few kHz.

Comment: You probably won't find 32 PWM channels in any conventional MCU.  Something like two PCA9685's would work, or you could put a processor and a bunch of PWM timers in a small FPGA.  How often do you need to *modify* the width?   What else does the processor need to be doing?

Comment: I was searching for a multipurpose MCU with a lot of PWM channels also and ended up with [NXP's LPC1549](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10736.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjv7vHctKzeAhXJiywKHXsKBA0QFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1tc9vr1zSftK0JImh1ZVWP). It's not an STM and it doesn't have 32 PWM channels, but up to 28 is still much more than MCU's in general.

Comment: If frequencies are same for all PWMs, I would implement software pwm with one timer for such low frequencies.

Comment: The PWMs will be continuously updated as I will be controlling a remote robot real time.

Comment: Your best bet would be an external [LT8500](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt8500.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies. From what I understand, there are no STM32 MCUs with 32PWMs. 
Therefore, as Chris Stratton suggested, I will go with two PCA9685 which uses I2C to create 16 PWMs each.

EDIT: Ok so there are MCUs in the STM32F103 line with 100+ pins that has over 32PWMs.

Comment: Yes, there is, e.g. [the STM32F103 in 100+ pin packages](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/307654/93879)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) (free application from ST) to search for STM's with a specific amount of timers (I think also including what type, basic, general, advanced etc).

So first find out what kind of timers you need, fill it in the parameterized search within STM32CubeMX and you get a list of all applicable STMs.

Also, for just a few kHz, it might be feasible to not use timers, but do it directly with the CPU (although it will be CPU time costly).

Comment: The issue with the STM32CubeMX is that I can only specify the timers I need, which doesn't exactly say the number of PWM channels available (unless I'm doing it wrong).